# How to capture & pattern match for long command line args in Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm wanting to parse long command line args like this

--key=value
--key_name=value_value
--key-name=value-value

Where key name and value can contain either underscores or dashes or both
Anything not matching should be skipped.

This is what I have so far

```
local args = {...}
for i = 1, #args, 1 do   
   print("arg[i]=", args[i])
   local string = args[i]
   local k,v = string:match("%-%-([^=-]+)=([^=]+)")
   print("k=", k)
   print("v=", v)
end
```

Which works to an extent, but also matches ---key_name=value
i.e. 3 dashes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't forcing the match to happen at the start of your argument so it is happily skipping a leading `-` and matching the rest of the argument.

Small modification to your script to run stand-alone and to capture where the match starts:

```
for i = 1, #arg, 1 do
    print("arg[i]=", arg[i])
    local string = arg[i]
    local p,k,v = string:match("()%-%-([^=-]+)=([^=]+)")
    print("p=", p)
    print("k=", k)
    print("v=", v)
end
```

Running `./script.lua ---fook=foov --bark=barv` outputs:

```
arg[i]= ---fook=foov
p=      2
k=      fook
v=      foov
arg[i]= --bark=barv
p=      1
k=      bark
v=      barv
```

Compare to:

```
for i = 1, #arg, 1 do
    print("arg[i]=", arg[i])
    local string = arg[i]
    local p,k,v = string:match("^()%-%-([^=-]+)=([^=]+)")
    print("p=", p)
    print("k=", k)
    print("v=", v)
end
```

which outputs (for the same `./script.lua ---fook=foov --bark=barv`):

```
arg[i]= ---fook=foov
p=      nil
k=      nil
v=      nil
arg[i]= --bark=barv
p=      1
k=      bark
v=      barv
```

Also for the record `string` is a terrible name for a variable as you just clobbered the default `string` table of functions.